# Convert an empty value to 0

Tags: javascript

Consider this / Please try this yourself in the chrome console.

`data = [1,,2,,3]`

now i want to replace the empty values with 0

`data = [1,0,2,0,3]`

I did:

```
data = data.map(e => {

    if (e===undefined)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return e;
    }
});
```

But it is still returning the empty values as empty. what is right way to do this?

Comment: `e === null` should do the trick

Comment: No @goldie, it does not help

Comment: Another option is to return 0 unless the value passes the if test. Check typeof 'number', for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `map` doesn't call the function for the missing elements of the array. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including `undefined`. It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

The same is true of `forEach`.

You need to loop through the array indexes rather than using one of the mapping functions.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!(i in data)) {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that using `i in data` makes it only skip nonexistent entries. If you have an explicit `undefined` it will be left, e.g.

```
[1, , undefined, 3, 4]
```

will become

```
[1, 0, undefined, 3, 4]
```

If you want the explicit `undefined` to be replaced, you can use `i === undefined` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for the behavior

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is handy for this. It will use the `length` to iterate over the array so it won't skip undefined values like `map()` does. You can pass the value to its second parameter which is a function and return the value `or` 0:

```js
let data = [1,,2,,3]
let new_array = Array.from(data, i=> i || 0)

console.log(new_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying looping over the length of the array and filling the gaps:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    if(typeof(data[i]) === 'undefined')
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}
```